# Is there a way to transpose groups of columns to rows in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery, unpivot

My source table in excel looks like this:

```
code    name1   perc1   name2   perc2   name3   perc3
11      x       10      x2      20      x3      70
12      y       20      y2      80        
13      z      100              
45      q      15       q2      85
```

and here is the final table I need:

```
code    name1   perc1
11      x        10
11      x2       20
11      x3       70
12      y        20
12      y2       80 
13      z       100
45      q        15
45      q2       85
```

Comment: That does not look like transposing, but rather cut/paste/sort...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this using PowerQuery.The steps are as follows:

1. Merge columns name1 & perc1, name2 & perc2 , name3 & perc3, using a delimeter (say *equalsign*). Now your left with 4 columns.
2. Right-click column [code] and select `Unpivot Other Columns`
3. Right-click column [Attribute] and select `Remove`
4. Right-click column [Value] and select `Split Columns` => `By Delimeter`=> `OK`
5. Using the dropdown-menu in Column [Value.2]: deselect the null values.
6. Rename column [Value.1] and [Value.2]
7. Click `Close & Load`

This is the result in PowerQuery (just before step 7)

[image]

And this is the generated script from the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"code", Int64.Type}, {"name1", type text}, {"perc1", Int64.Type}, {"name2", type text}, {"perc2", Int64.Type}, {"name3", type text}, {"perc3", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"perc1", type text}}, "en-US"),{"name1", "perc1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("=", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns", {{"perc2", type text}}, "en-US"),{"name2", "perc2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("=", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.1"),
    #"Merged Columns2" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns1", {{"perc3", type text}}, "en-US"),{"name3", "perc3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("=", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged.2"),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Merged Columns2", {"code"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("=", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1", "Value.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Value.1", type text}, {"Value.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each ([Value.2] <> null)),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Value.1", "Name1"}, {"Value.2", "Perc1"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: Nice demo of use of `PQ`.  What if there are a variable number of `Name|Perc` pairs of columns, though?

Answer (score 2):

For example like so:

[image]

Formula in `J2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,SMALL(($B$2:$G$5<>"")*(ISEVEN(COLUMN($B$2:$G$5)))*(ROW($B$2:$G$5)-1),COUNTA($B$2:$G$5)-SUMPRODUCT((ISEVEN(COLUMN(B2:G5))))+(ROW()-1))),"")
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Formula in `K2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$G$5,MATCH(J2,$A$2:$A$5,0),COUNTIF($J$2:J2,J2)*2)
```

Formula in `L2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$G$5,MATCH(J2,$A$2:$A$5,0),(COUNTIF($J$2:J2,J2)*2)+1)
```

Drag them down....

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep this about *transposing*, I used a transposed array to build the target.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeGroups()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arr1 As Variant
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, arr2 As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet1")

        arr1 = .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion.Value2

        ReDim arr2(1 To 3, 1 To (UBound(arr1, 2) - 1) / 2 * (UBound(arr1, 1) - 1))

        m = 1
        For n = 1 To 3
            arr2(n, m) = arr1(m, n)
        Next n

        For i = 2 To UBound(arr1, 1)
            For j = 2 To UBound(arr1, 2) Step 2

                If arr1(i, j) = vbNullString Then Exit For

                m = m + 1
                arr2(1, m) = arr1(i, 1)
                arr2(2, m) = arr1(i, j)
                arr2(3, m) = arr1(i, j + 1)

            Next j
        Next i

        With .Parent.Worksheets.Add(after:=.Parent.Worksheets(.Index))

            .Cells(1, "A").Resize(UBound(arr2, 2), UBound(arr2, 1)) = _
                Application.Transpose(arr2)

        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that is great.